# How to get Total for a DataSet.DataTable on a GridView?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a gridview that shows (50)rows of data per page.  I have the Total showing for the Amount that is shown due to a previous request by the user.  Now they want to have the total for the Entire result, regardless of what page they are on.  How do I do that?

I did the following for my Complete Total Count:

After the Gridview result gets populated in table

```
Count = dsReport.DataTable1.Count;
```

My plan for the Complete Total that has so far failed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) 
{ Total += dsPoint.DataTable1.Columns[3].Row[i]; ??? I dont know what to do }
```

What is the sum of the specific Decimal Column[3]?  Even though I display 50 results, I need the Total for the ENTIRE column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
Total = dsPoint.Tables["DataTable1"].Compute("SUM(columnName)", String.Empty);
```

You provide the `columnName` :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have it backwards. Typically to get to a value in a DataTable you'll want to use DataTable.Row[i].Column[j]. So assuming you have an integer in your column, you can run your total like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) 
{ 
   Total += Integer.Parse(dsPoint.DataTable1.Rows[i].Columns[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [Compute method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) of the datatable. It is much easier than looping through the datatables.